# Need to remove leading spaces from a COBOL pic clause?

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I need to be able to remove all leading spaces from a String in Cobol PIC x(80)

Code:

```
      UNSTRING ADDRESS DELIMITED BY SPACES INTO
 -             S-SP, ADDRESS              
 -    END-UNSTRING.
```

Then I should be able to write the string ADDRESS to a file without any leading spaces.

Error code:

> 775  IGYPS0088-S   The "UNSTRING" statement was invalid.  Expected "INTO", but found "INTOWS-SPACES".  The statement was                     discarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specified "continuations", minus-signs/dashes in column 7 of your source.

Continuations are very, very, rarely required. They are only required for continuing a literal.

Remove the "-"s from column 7.

I don't think your code will do what you think, but if you have trouble with that, please ask a new question.

When a literal is continued, the closing quote is not included on the lined being continued.

```
   "ABCDE<and then column 72 arrives
-  "FGHIJ"
```

This literal will be "ABCDEFGHIJ" when used.

If you use the continuation on a line of code, the text will be concatenated without any intervening space, hence your error message.